# Getting this error "Must have exactly 1 query in the value of @Query or @DatabaseView" in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, dao

I need some help. I am getting this error "Must have exactly 1 query in the value of @Query or @DatabaseView"  in my android studio project when I build my project. I am getting this error in my cartdao.java file code is here:

`package com.example.xyz;`

`import androidx.room.Dao;`

`import androidx.room.Delete;`

`import androidx.room.Insert;`

`import androidx.room.Query;`

`import java.util.List;`

@Dao
public interface CartDao {

```
@Insert
void insertNew(CartOffline cartOffline);

@Query("")
List<CartOffline> getall();

@Query("")
List<CartOffline>  getCartProduct(String priceUnitId);

@Query("")
void updateObj(long quantity, String priceunitid);


@Query("")
void deleteObjbyPid(String priceunitid);

@Delete
void deleteObj(CartOffline cartOffline);

@Query("")
int getProductCount(String pId);

@Query("")
void deleteAll();
/*@Query("UPDATE CartOffline SET quantity = :quantity")
void updetCart()*/
```

}

Comment: Hi @Ayesha. Can you please provide the code which you used? I am actually unable to understand what is answered by `AndroidDev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding query

Ex your getAll function  should return data from some table.
Add queries to each of fun where you defined @Query annotation.

Comment: Yes, now it's working. Thanks a lot :)