# Someone help me with this error in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, compiler-errors, adb

Can anyone help me with this problem, I click on start debug to open the app on the phone and these errors appear...

Follow the photo below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwfA.png)

```
package com.retrytech.veginew does not exist
import com.retrytech.veginew.R;
```

Thank you and I'll be waiting

Comment: Please do not paste error message in screenshots only, just copy and paste the error text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is occurring because you are trying to import the `R` class from the wrong package. To solve it you need to remove that import and add this instead :

```
import com.frankpetapp.R;
```

Comment: I did what you said and I get this error now..

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoZDN.png

Comment: can you tell me the package name of the app?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how do I see the name of the app to send you?
I am still learning

Comment: open the android manifest and send the image.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCaiF.png

Comment: I have edited the answer.please check

Comment: I did what you said and now I'm getting this error when I try to run it again

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwdtg.png

Comment: click ALT + ENTER and click on import

Comment: I'm pressing ALT Enter and nothing appears this import part

Comment: please send image

Comment: are you using windows or Mac?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slJ3i.png

Comment: yes click import class

Comment: I use windows..

Comment: ok click on `Import Class`

Comment: There are several errors appearing like the 2 I mentioned, I change to import com.frankpetapp.R;
and I always give import class?

Comment: yes. it will give. this because you are changing the class.

Comment: I'm finishing going through everyone here and I already give you an answer and I accept

Comment: I did all that was appearing and now it stuck in this error friend...
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyB8P.png

Comment: that is not related to this question. Please ask another question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean friend

Comment: I mean that in this question you are asking about an import error. Not this one. So I am asking you to ask another question.

Comment: And sorry to say but I have dont have a lot of knowledge about retrofit.

Comment: you can refer to this question for this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280038/getting-this-error-must-have-exactly-1-query-in-the-value-of-query-or-databas

Comment: Thank you friend, I'll take the answer for granted and I'll look for help, thank you very much from the heart

Comment: I managed to fix it with alt+enter and clicking, but now I got stuck on this error

error: cannot find symbol
import com.frankpetapp.databinding.ItemCouponlistBindingImpl;
                                   ^
   symbol: class ItemCouponlistBindingImpl
   location: package com.frankpetapp.databinding